# Why isn't GestureDetector working in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

Gesture Detector isn't working - why not?
print or Navigator not working

```
    GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  ... ;
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  width: 170,
                  height: 60,
                  child:...
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: You need to add more code in order to solve your issue. What widget did you enclosed inside the tap gesture? Is it visible on screen? Maybe a screenshot with your UI will help too.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Often times, this is because your `GestureDetector` is a child of another Widget that has an `onTap` property. For example, if you give an `ElevatedButton` a child of `GestureDetector`, this `GestureDetector`'s `onTap` is never reached, due to the `ElevatedButton` overruling its `onTap` property.